# Quadratic function solver + testing

Tags: java, junit

I wrote a simple quadratic function solver with unit tests. Can anyone check if this is okay?

Quadratic function class

```
public class QuadraticFunction {
    private Integer a,b,c;

    public QuadraticFunction(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Result calculate() throws NullPointerException{
        if(calculateDelta()>0){
          return new DeltaBiggerThanZero(calculateX1(),calculateX2());
        }else if(calculateDelta() == 0){
            return new DeltaEqualsZero(calculateOneRoot());
        }else{
            return new NoSolution();
        }
    }

    private Double calculateDelta(){
        return Math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c;
    }

    private Double rootOfDelta(){
        return Math.sqrt(calculateDelta());
    }

    private Double calculateX1(){
        return (-b-rootOfDelta())/2*a;
    }

    private Double calculateX2(){
        return (-b+rootOfDelta())/2*a;
    }

    private Double calculateOneRoot(){
        return Double.valueOf((-b)/2*a);
    }
```

Result class example

```
final public class DeltaBiggerThanZero implements Result{

    private Double x1, x2;

    public Double getX1() {
        return x1;
    }

    public Double getX2() {
        return x2;
    }

    public DeltaBiggerThanZero(Double x1, Double x2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
    }
    public String printSimpleResult() {
        return "Rozwiązaniem równiania jest: x1="+x1+" x2="+x2;
    }
}
```

This is a test:

```
public class QuadraticFunctionTest {
    @Test
    public void testIfEquationHasTwoResults() throws Exception {
        QuadraticFunction quadraticFunction = new QuadraticFunction(1,-4,-5);
        Result result = new DeltaBiggerThanZero(-1.0,5.0);

        assertEquals(quadraticFunction.calculate().getX1(), result.getX1());
        assertEquals(quadraticFunction.calculate().getX2(), result.getX2());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIfEquationHasOneResult(){
        QuadraticFunction quadraticFunction = new QuadraticFunction(1,6,9);
        Result result = new DeltaEqualsZero(-3.0);

        assertEquals(result.getX1(), quadraticFunction.calculate().getX1());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIfTheresNoSolution() throws Exception {
        QuadraticFunction quadraticFunction = new QuadraticFunction(1,2,5);
        Result result = new NoSolution();
        assertEquals(quadraticFunction.calculate().getX1(), null);
        assertEquals(quadraticFunction.calculate().getX2(), null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks good, nice and clean. Nitpicks:

- no need to introduce a method called `printSimpleResult` when you can simply override `toString` (either way, the "print" part is a lie as the method *returns* the string, doesn't *print* it)
- missing `@Override` annotation in `DeltaBiggerThanZero`
- naming a variable "result" in the tests is a bit ambiguous, especially since it seems that you don't know what order of params `assertEquals` takes in (it's "expected, actual", for the record)
- why artificially limit input parameters `a`, `b`, `c` to integers only?
- what's the purpose of `throws NullPointerException` in `calculate`'s signature? I see no way in which this exception could be triggered, and you're not required to declare unchecked exceptions ([and it's a matter of discussion whether you should](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20871763/1240557))

You didn't include the code for `NoSolution` but apparently it's an implementation that returns `null` for most of the fields. This begs for using Java 8's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). Returning `null` and hoping the clients will know and remember how to interpret it is a bad idea.

On the other hand, creating a class hierarchy for different kinds of solutions is rather problematic for the client (arguably this is *not* the scenario that calls for inheritance, which should be used judiciously). Since `calculate()` returns an abstract `Result`, the client still needs to do "sniffing" on the returned object to figure out how many (if any) results there were. They could to this either by checking via `instanceof` or trying to see what `x1` and `x2` are (if `x2` is `null` it must be the "delta-is-zero" case, if both `x1` and `x2` are `null` it must be the "delta-is-negative" case with no solutions). Neither of these options is elegant or clean. A better solution could be to return a `List<Double>` that has either zero, one or two elements in it. A simple implementation that would allow you to get rid of the `Result` type and its subclasses could be:

```
public List<Double> calculate() {
    Double delta = calculateDelta();
    if (delta > 0) {
        return new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(new Double[] { calculateX1(), calculateX2() }));
    } else if (delta == 0) {
        return new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(new Double[] { calculateOneRoot() }));
    } else {
        return Collections.<Double> emptyList();
    }
}
```

A `List` has a nice default implementation of `toString()` so the client calling the code above could just do:

```
QuadraticFunction qf = new QuadraticFunction(1, -4, -5);
List<Double> results = qf.calculate();
System.out.println("Rozwiązania to: " + results);
```

To get the output of:

> Rozwiązania to: [-1.0, 5.0]

Comment: Thank you for response. Could you give me an example using List<Double> ?

Comment: @mattsky updated the answer with a simple example